# Change language and currency by user location

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Does anyone know how to automaticaly change the currency and language based by user location? I have only two languages in my store and i want that the users from my country to access one language and local currency, and if it is from another country the language to be english, and currency Euro.

Comment: some extension available for that. please find third party extension in OpenCart market. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/

Comment: i've looged and there's none

Comment: please check this- http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=currency%20and%20language%20by%20user%20location